# How to use the @salesforce/design-system-react package in my Create-React-App

Tags: reactjs, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have an ejected React app that is based on Create-React-App, and I am trying to install the @salesforce/design-system-react package to use the Salesforce lightning components in it. But to use this package is not as easy (seems that I need some extra configuration for Barbel and Webpeck). I don't have much experience on config Barbel and Webpeck and need some help to get me started.

Can someone please let me know how can I get that .BABELRC and the Webpack v1 files described from this site: https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/getting-started/ ?

Many thanks,

Comment: It is a little difficult to troubleshoot an ejected Create React App, especially without seeing any code. Are you able to do a new install of CRA and get Design System React running? I'd try that first.

Second, I would recommend getting the [CommonJS module][1] and not the source code version working first. Have you been able to get that working? That way you will not need Babel, nor a special Webpack config, since it's standard Node JavaScript.

  [1]: https://github.com/salesforce/design-system-react#quick-setup-commonjs

Comment: I saw your entire post https://github.com/salesforce/design-system-react/issues/1331 and it looked like you got the CJS version working, but without CSS. The easiest way to get CSS working without ejecting is to copy /node_modules/@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css to public and put   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css"> in index.html

Comment: Thanks, LIama. This resolves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

No need to configure anything. Just import the CSS.

In your index.js, add the following line.

`import "@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css";`

Now you should remove the styling in App.css since the default styling in Create React App will affect your Lightning Components (font-size for example)